# How do we correct an error in the button "previous" in SurveyMonkey?

Tags: surveymonkey

When using the Surveymonkey appli, the button "previous" between each question has an orthographical error in French. It reads "Pr&#233", instead of "Préc." 
Is it due to the fact that I copy/paste an ancient survey? How can this be fixed?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of SurveyMonkey required HTML codes for non-US characters. Now you can just enter "Préc". It's simpler now, but might require some updating for old surveys.

Comment: Note to fix it, if you're using "Classic Design" you need to go to "Survey Options" in the Survey Editor to change this, and if you're using "New Design" you can just edit the button directly in the editor.